# Python code for ldapsearch

Tags: python, ldap-query

I have a script:

```
ldapsearch -xLL -h 10.4.113.46 -D 'E900000@corp.privatedev' -W -b 'dc=corp,dc=privatedev' '(cn=lc_proxy_pentest)'
```

It runs well.

I programme with python to make the same query:

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL
....
server = Server('10.4.113.46', get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(server, 'uid=E900000@corp.privatedev,cn=lc_proxy_pentest,dc=corp,dc=privatedev', 'PaSsWoRd', auto_bind=True)
```

The error shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<input>", line 1, in <module>   
File "C:\Users\E900000\Python\lib\site-packages\ldap3\core\connection.py", line 278, in __init__
    self.bind(read_server_info=True)   
File "C:\Users\E900000\Python\lib\site-packages\ldap3\core\connection.py", line 427, in bind
    response = self.post_send_single_response(self.send('bindRequest', request, controls))   
File "C:\Users\E900000\Python\lib\site-packages\ldap3\strategy\sync.py", line 122, in post_send_single_response
    responses, result = self.get_response(message_id)   
File "C:\Users\E900000\Python\lib\site-packages\ldap3\strategy\base.py", line 298, in get_response
    responses = self._get_response(message_id)   
File "C:\Users\E900000\Python\lib\site-packages\ldap3\strategy\sync.py", line 168, in _get_response
    dict_response = self.decode_response(ldap_resp)  
File "C:\Users\E900000\Python\lib\site-packages\ldap3\strategy\base.py", line 403, in decode_response
    result = bind_response_to_dict(component)   
File "C:\Users\E900000\Python\lib\site-packages\ldap3\operation\bind.py", line 119, in bind_response_to_dict
    'saslCreds': bytes(response['serverSaslCreds']) if response['serverSaslCreds'] is not None else None}   
File "C:\Users\E900000\Python\lib\site-packages\pyasn1\type\univ.py", line 984, in __bytes__
    return bytes(self._value) TypeError: cannot convert 'NoValue' object to bytes
```

If I programme just

```
server = Server('10.4.113.46')
conn = Connection(server)
conn.bind()
```

The third line brings the same error.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that E900000@corp.privatedev corresponds to uid=E900000@corp.privatedev,cn=lc_proxy_pentest,dc=corp,dc=privatedev

I am assuming you are using Active Directory (based on E900000@corp.privatedev).

Try using dsquery to [Determine the FDN for the user](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Determining%20the%20FDN).

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the failed connection can be refered https://github.com/etingof/pyasn1/issues/52.

But after I modify the library and enable a successful connection, the ldapsearch still doesn‘t work.